# TypeError: $(...).foundation is not a function - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

I want to itegrate Foundation 6 in Magento but i get this error on app.js file on `$(document).foundation()`

I just try with jQuery(document).foundation() but does not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved moving app.js after foundation.min.js in magento footer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl('js'); ?>pm/foundation/vendor/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl('js'); ?>pm/foundation/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl('js'); ?>pm/foundation/app.js"></script>
```

changing code in app.js with

```
jQuery(document).foundation()
```